# Particle system - steers along path

Tags: particles, force-fields

I have few arrows to follow a particular path such a way that the arrows will always orient along (steer along) the path. Using 'curve guide', I was able to make the arrows flow along the path, but the arrows do not change direction according to the path.
[image: Some arrows are in wrong direction]

As you can see arrows are always facing the same direction. What I want is the arrows should change the direction according to the path.

I tried my level best. But no result :( Please help me. you can find my Blender file also.
[Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2piSDHkvL_6Z1UwbUJkRGlQUzA/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks and Regards Sabin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First make the arrow point in X direction by editing the mesh:

[image]

Then enable *Rotation* tab for particle system and check *Dynamic*:

[image]

Your particles will now rotate along the Curve guide accordingly:

[image]